# Determine the maximal ideals of $\mathbb R^2$ by determining **all** its ideals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

This is a letter of an exericse in Artin Algebra and has been asked and answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532867/determine-the-maximal-ideals-of-mathbbr2) as well as by Brian Bi [here](http://brianbi.ca/artin/11.8) and Takumi Murayama [here](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b01902113/artin-sols.pdf). I had a different approach [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3049236) and have yet another approach.

[image]

$\mathbb R$ is a field so its only ideals are $(1)$ and $(0)$. Thus, by [Structure of ideals in the product of two rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101214/structure-of-ideals-in-the-product-of-two-rings) **all** the ideals of $\mathbb R^2$ are $$(0)\times(0),(1)\times(1),(0)\times(1),(1)\times(0)$$. Then it's obvious $$(0)\times(1),(1)\times(0)$$ are the maximal ideals.

Is this correct also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since $(1) \times (1) = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ is the whole ring and $(0) \times (0)$ is contained in both $(0) \times (1)$ and $(1) \times (0)$. It is also clear that $(0) \times (1) \not \subset (1) \times (0)$ and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you 0x539! I have to wait for 6-8 minutes to accept an answer.